# Dual Boot (Windows 10 and Ubuntu Mate) boots to Grub command line

Tags: command-line, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, ubuntu-mate

So, for the record, I'm new to using Ubuntu/Linux. I'm slowly getting acquainted with everything, but I'd love it if you guys could help me out with an issue I'm having.

I have a laptop with two hard drives. On one of the drives, Windows 10 is preinstalled. On the other, I installed Ubuntu Mate. I can boot into both OS's fine, but whenever I boot into Windows and reboot, the Grub command line comes up. If I type `exit`, it exits the command line and goes into the grub bootloader as expected. From there, it works perfectly.

If I reboot from Ubuntu, it doesn't go to the command line, it goes straight to the bootloader. The command line only comes up after rebooting the computer from Windows.

I can live with having to type `exit` on the command line whenever I use Windows. It's only a minor inconvenience (so far), but if there's a way to prevent this from happening, I love to figure it out. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try running `sudo update-grub` and also disable Fast Startup in Windows.

Comment: Just wanted to check back in and let you know that your solution actually worked. I had originally disabled Fast Boot from the Control Panel in Windows, but I just realized there's a Fast Boot option in the BIOS as well. Disabling that has fixed the issue I was having. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'll keep it mind for the time. You're  not the first with this problem and you won't be the last :( . The solution is your though. Fast Startup is a Windows  feature, Fast Boot is a feature found in some UEFI (repleces the old BIOS). You can answer your own question and later accept it and get some point :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem thanks to another user here. The issue was Fast Startup, which is a Windows feature. It was interfering with GRUB and causing the issue with the command line popping up first. Disabling Fast Startup stopped the issue from occuring. Thanks, GabrielaGarcia for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I installed Ubuntu (by adding a new drive) I made sure that all "Fast Boot" settings in the computer bios and Windows OS were disabled. After a "Windows Update" I suddenly started booting to grub shell after booting to Windows. Checking the Windows OS first I found that my settings were untouched. Checking the Bios, well...

Changed the Bios back to Fast Boot "disabled" and everything works fine once again. (a little OS turf war going on there? Microsoft digging their heels in to slow the inevitable?) The real issue is Microsoft changing Bios settings without the user input.