# Unable to login into newly installed Ubuntu! Stuck in GRUB2 command line!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I recently installed Ubuntu 18 (dual boot alongside Windows 10), after it took time to update, I restarted (as instructed after the update) the OS and now I am unable to login into it. After every boot, a GRUB2 command-line is coming up, from which I'm unable to escape! By exiting the command-line I am only able to boot into Windows!
Can anyone help?

[Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZlPhfho315iwvYaGmfqFbPZAI_UoAoDK/view?usp=drivesdk)

**EDIT:** Ok for now I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS & I was able to fix a few of the issues (probably the major ones I guess). I upgraded the OS to 20.04 version. I am able login to Ubuntu as well but through Windows' "Advance Startup", as I am not getting the GRUB2 at boot!
Is it because I haven't given the free partition from C:\ (I freed up space space by shrinking E:\ disk & allocated the partition to Ubuntu)?

Comment: Upon boot up, does Ubuntu stop booting at some point and enter Rescue Mode?

Comment: My machine actually directly boots up into Windows. I use "Advance Startup" from Windows to log into Ubuntu. That's when I am facing the issue, & I am not seeing any "rescue" mode.

Comment: Sorry, Rescue Mode is the name for when Ubuntu boots up and goes into a BASH command line. I just decided to look at the screenshot and I saw that it was definitely not BASH but GRUB2, like you said it was in the first place. That being said, it seems like either the installation of Ubuntu may have failed at some point, or Windows is just being stupid and not detecting the Ubuntu partition. I would recommend looking at your Windows Advanced Startup options, and, if there is nothing wrong with those, attempting to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, @Jeff for the advice. For now, me being totally clueless regarding how to resolve the issue, I will probably reinstall it if I don't find any solution!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dual Boot (Windows 10 and Ubuntu Mate) boots to Grub command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093055/dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-mate-boots-to-grub-command-line)

Comment: Unfortunately no! I already have the fast-boot disabled!

Comment: What happens if you select "Ubuntu" at UEFI > Boot.

Comment: Sorry, where exactly?

Comment: From the UEFI one time boot menu. With HP most are <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>  or the same keys you used to boot live installer to install Ubuntu. But HP does not support changes to UEFI boot order except from within its own UEFI menu. <kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>  But different models may use different keys. Check your manual.

Comment: Ubuntu 18?    Ubuntu desktop and server releases have a *yy.mm* format, and whilst specialist snap based releases like Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances do use a *yy* format there are none titled just Ubuntu 18.  Please clarify your release as there is no Ubuntu 18; do you mean a Ubuntu Core 18 install?

Comment: Ok for now I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS & I was able to fix a few of the issues (probably the major ones I guess). I upgraded the OS to 20.04 version. I am able login to Ubuntu as well but through Windows' "Advance Startup", as I am not getting the GRUB2 at boot!